# How to use tileOverlays on google_maps_flutter package?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, wms

With java, we can put WMS tiles on top of Google Base Map by making use of tile overlays. In flutter i found google_maps_flutter has tileOverlays property on its constructor but it very hard to find a working example. Anyone here successfully overlay WMS tiles on top of google maps in flutter?

Comment: You can simply stack as many widgets as you want using position widgets.

Comment: You can check the sample from the `google_maps_flutter` package here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/tile_overlay.dart

Answer (score 12):

I managed to make it work.

### Context is the following:

I had to show custom tiles created from drone images. The goal was to have a much better resolution on the images between zoom levels 14 and 22.

The API I had to work with didn't have images for the whole map which makes sense because we were only interested in having details for some areas.

However, I could fetch on the API [KML layers files](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/help/data/kml/kml-layers.htm) which allowed me to know in advance what images I could fetch.

Those KML files define coordinates of the tiles I could download from the API.

### Resolution

#### 1)

The first step was to fetch thoses KML files and parse them in order to find which regions were covered by drone images. (Not the point here but I can show you anyway if you wish)

#### 2)

Then I made a custom [TileProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/TileProvider-class.html). You basically have to everride a method called [`getTile`](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/TileProvider/getTile.html).

This method has to return a [Tile](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Tile-class.html).
A tile in Flutter is basically an object containing a width, a height and and datas as `Uint8List`.

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class TestTileProvider implements TileProvider{
  @override
  Future<Tile> getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    // TODO: implement getTile
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
```

Those data can be easily created by drawing on a canvas as suggested in the [official example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/tile_overlay.dart).

```
  @override
  Future<Tile> getTile(int x, int y, int? zoom) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    final TextSpan textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: '$x,$y',
      style: textStyle,
    );
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0.0,
      maxWidth: width.toDouble(),
    );
    final Offset offset = const Offset(0, 0);
    textPainter.paint(canvas, offset);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, width.toDouble(), width.toDouble()), boxPaint);
    final ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final Uint8List byteData = await picture
        .toImage(width, height)
        .then((ui.Image image) =>
            image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
        .then((ByteData? byteData) => byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
    return Tile(width, height, byteData);
  }
```

The problem was that it didn't fit my needs as I had to display real pictures and not draw border and Tiles coordinates on Tiles.

I found a way to load network images and convert them into the correct format for the Tile.

```
final uri = Uri.https(AppUrl.BASE, imageUri);
try {
  final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(uri).load("");
  final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
  return Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, bytes);
} catch (e) {}
```

However, as I don't have images for the whole map, I had to return something when no image was available. I made a transparent tile and returned it when needed. In order to improve performances, I create the transparent Tile when I create the provider and then always return the same one.

```
class TestTileProvider implements TileProvider {
  static const int TILE_SIZE = 256;
  static final Paint boxPaint = Paint();
  Tile transparentTile;
...
  TestTileProvider() {
    boxPaint.isAntiAlias = true;
    boxPaint.color = Colors.transparent;
    boxPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    initTransparentTile();
  }
...

  void initTransparentTile() async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, TILE_SIZE.toDouble(), TILE_SIZE.toDouble()),
        boxPaint);
    final ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final Uint8List byteData = await picture
        .toImage(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)
        .then((ui.Image image) =>
            image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
        .then((ByteData byteData) => byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
    transparentTile = Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, byteData);
  }
...

}
```

The next problem I encountered is that this `getTile` method only gives you Tile coordinates (`x`, `y` and `zoom`) in the *Tile world*. The locations defined in KML Layers are defined in *Degrees*.

```
<LatLonAltBox>
    <north>47.054785</north>
    <south>47.053557</south>
    <east>6.780674</east>
    <west>6.774709</west>
</LatLonAltBox>
```

(Those are fake coordinates I can't show you the real one :) )

I really, REALLY, **REALLY** suggest you [to read this](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) in order to understand the differences between all those coordinates types.

I then had to find a way to convert tiles coordinates to degrees.

As I couldn't find anyway in Flutter to retrieve a [projection object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#Projection) (In javascript API there's a way to retrieve it). I had to convert those coordinates by myself.

First I had to understand how they are converted from degrees to tile coordinates (This uses a [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) and some math).

Hopefully I could find a JS implementation [here in the `project` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1).

The "only" thing I had to do was to invert this and I would be able to obtain degrees from tile coordinates.

I first rewrote the `project` method and then inverted it:

```
// The mapping between latitude, longitude and pixels is defined by the web
  // mercator projection.
  // Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1
  math.Point project(LatLng latLng) {
    double siny = math.sin((latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180);

    // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
    // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
    siny = math.min(math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

    return new math.Point(
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360),
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi)),
    );
  }

  LatLng reverseMercatorFromTileCoordinates(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    // Reverse mercator projection.
    // Reverse of above function (kept for readibility)
    //
    // 1) Compute longitude
    //
    // TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360) = x
    //0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360 = x / TILE_SIZE
    // latLng.longitude / 360 = x / TILE_SIZE - 0.5
    // latLng.longitude = (x / TILE_SIZE - 0.5) *360

    int pixelCoordinateX = x * TILE_SIZE;
    int pixelCoordinateY = y * TILE_SIZE;

    double worldCoordinateX = pixelCoordinateX / math.pow(2, zoom);
    double worldCoordinateY = pixelCoordinateY / math.pow(2, zoom);

    double long = (worldCoordinateX / TILE_SIZE - 0.5) * 360;

    //
    // 2) compute sin(y)
    //
    // TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi)) = y
    // 0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi) = y / TILE_SIZE
    // math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi) = -(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5
    // math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) = (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)
    // (1 + siny) / (1 - siny) = math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi))
    // siny = (math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)) - 1) / (1+math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)));
    double part = math.pow(
        math.e, ((-(worldCoordinateY / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5) * (4 * math.pi)));
    double siny = (part - 1) / (1 + part);
    //
    // 3) Compute latitude
    //
    // siny = math.sin((latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180)
    // math.asin(siny) = (latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180
    // math.asin(siny) * 180 = (latLng.latitude * math.pi)
    // (math.asin(siny) * 180) / math.pi = latLng.latitude
    double lat = (math.asin(siny) * 180) / math.pi;
    return LatLng(lat, long);
  }
```

I was now able to check if the Tile requested from the Provider was in the areas covered by drone images!

Here's the full `getTile` implementation:

```
  @override
  Future<Tile> getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) async {

    // Reverse tile coordinates to degreees
    LatLng tileNorthWestCornerCoordinates =
        reverseMercatorFromTileCoordinates(x, y, zoom);

    // `domain` is an object in which are stored the kml datas fetched before
    KMLLayer kmlLayer =
        domain.getKMLLayerforPoint(tileNorthWestCornerCoordinates);

    
    if (kmlLayer != null &&
        zoom >= kmlLayer.minZoom &&
        zoom <= kmlLayer.maxZoom) {
      final String imageUri = domain.getImageUri(kmlLayer, x, y, zoom);

      final uri = Uri.https(AppUrl.BASE, imageUri);
      try {
        final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(uri).load("");
        final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
        return Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, bytes);
      } catch (e) {}
    }
    // return transparent tile
    return transparentTile;
  }
```

Anddddddddd the full `TileProvider` example:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:app_digivitis/core/constants/app_url.dart';
import 'package:app_digivitis/core/models/domain.dart';
import 'package:app_digivitis/core/models/kml_layer.dart';
import 'package:app_digivitis/core/viewmodels/screens/user_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class TestTileProvider implements TileProvider {
  static const int TILE_SIZE = 256;
  static final Paint boxPaint = Paint();
  BuildContext context;
  Tile transparentTile;
  Domain domain;

  TestTileProvider() {
    boxPaint.isAntiAlias = true;
    boxPaint.color = Colors.transparent;
    boxPaint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    initTransparentTile();
  }

  @override
  Future<Tile> getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) async {
    // Reverse tile coordinates to degreees
    LatLng tileNorthWestCornerCoordinates =
        reverseMercatorFromTileCoordinates(x, y, zoom);

    // `domain` is an object in which are stored the kml datas fetched before
    KMLLayer kmlLayer =
        domain.getKMLLayerforPoint(tileNorthWestCornerCoordinates);

    if (kmlLayer != null &&
        zoom >= kmlLayer.minZoom &&
        zoom <= kmlLayer.maxZoom) {
      final String imageUri = domain.getImageUri(kmlLayer, x, y, zoom);

      final uri = Uri.https(AppUrl.BASE, imageUri);
      try {
        final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(uri).load("");
        final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
        return Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, bytes);
      } catch (e) {}
    }
    // return transparent tile
    return transparentTile;
  }

  void initContext(BuildContext context) {
    context = context;
    final userViewModel = Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    domain = userViewModel.domain;
  }

  void initTransparentTile() async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder);
    canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, TILE_SIZE.toDouble(), TILE_SIZE.toDouble()),
        boxPaint);
    final ui.Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final Uint8List byteData = await picture
        .toImage(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE)
        .then((ui.Image image) =>
            image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))
        .then((ByteData byteData) => byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
    transparentTile = Tile(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, byteData);
  }

  // The mapping between latitude, longitude and pixels is defined by the web
  // mercator projection.
  // Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1
  math.Point project(LatLng latLng) {
    double siny = math.sin((latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180);

    // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
    // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
    siny = math.min(math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

    return new math.Point(
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360),
      TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi)),
    );
  }

  LatLng reverseMercatorFromTileCoordinates(int x, int y, int zoom) {
    // Reverse mercator projection.
    // Reverse of above function (kept for readibility)
    //
    // 1) Compute longitude
    //
    // TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360) = x
    //0.5 + latLng.longitude / 360 = x / TILE_SIZE
    // latLng.longitude / 360 = x / TILE_SIZE - 0.5
    // latLng.longitude = (x / TILE_SIZE - 0.5) *360

    int pixelCoordinateX = x * TILE_SIZE;
    int pixelCoordinateY = y * TILE_SIZE;

    double worldCoordinateX = pixelCoordinateX / math.pow(2, zoom);
    double worldCoordinateY = pixelCoordinateY / math.pow(2, zoom);

    double long = (worldCoordinateX / TILE_SIZE - 0.5) * 360;

    //
    // 2) compute sin(y)
    //
    // TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi)) = y
    // 0.5 - math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi) = y / TILE_SIZE
    // math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * math.pi) = -(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5
    // math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) = (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)
    // (1 + siny) / (1 - siny) = math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi))
    // siny = (math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)) - 1) / (1+math.pow(math.e, (-(y / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5)(4 * math.pi)));
    double part = math.pow(
        math.e, ((-(worldCoordinateY / TILE_SIZE) + 0.5) * (4 * math.pi)));
    double siny = (part - 1) / (1 + part);
    //
    // 3) Compute latitude
    //
    // siny = math.sin((latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180)
    // math.asin(siny) = (latLng.latitude * math.pi) / 180
    // math.asin(siny) * 180 = (latLng.latitude * math.pi)
    // (math.asin(siny) * 180) / math.pi = latLng.latitude
    double lat = (math.asin(siny) * 180) / math.pi;
    return LatLng(lat, long);
  }
}
```

Don't pay much attention to context as I needed it in order to use the provider to retrieve my `domain` instance.

#### 3)

Use this provider!

Full widget with map example:

```
import 'package:app_digivitis/core/providers/test_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class MarksMapTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MarksMapTestState createState() => _MarksMapTestState();
}

class _MarksMapTestState extends State<MarksMapTest>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Location _location = Location();
  LocationData _center =
      LocationData.fromMap({'latitude': 51.512153, 'longitude': -0.111019});
  TileOverlay _tileOverlay;
  TestTileProvider testTileProvider = TestTileProvider();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createTileOverlay();
    _location.getLocation().then((value) {
      _center = value;
    });
  }

  void createTileOverlay() {
    if (_tileOverlay == null) {
      final TileOverlay tileOverlay = TileOverlay(
        tileOverlayId: TileOverlayId('tile_overlay_1'),
        tileProvider: testTileProvider,
      );
      _tileOverlay = tileOverlay;
    }
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    centerMap(location: _center);
  }

  void centerMap({LocationData location}) async {
    if (location == null) location = await _location.getLocation();
    mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), zoom: 14)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    testTileProvider.initContext(context);
    Set<TileOverlay> overlays = <TileOverlay>{
      if (_tileOverlay != null) _tileOverlay,
    };
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) => _onMapCreated(controller),
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(_center.latitude, _center.longitude),
          zoom: 14.0,
        ),
        tileOverlays: overlays,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        mapToolbarEnabled: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maël, but how can I add a custom tile URL?

Comment: what do you mean? @زياد

Comment: Could you accept my answer? It would give more visibility to other users who may need an answer on this topic too. @زياد

Comment: @MaëlPedretti Hello, could you share this entire code please?

Comment: Hey @TimMwaura, this project is an entreprise project so I am afraid I won't be able to do it but I could make another example if you find an open databank of drone images